# Better SQL query to remove equivalent rows

Tags: sql, ms-access

Guys, I'm new at SQL and can't figure out the "right way" to do the last part of a query.  I have a table which contains a list of items and their equivalents.  There are essentially twice as many rows as needed, and I'm trying to find a SQL way to select 1/2 of the entries so there are no duplicates.

Starting Table with duplicates:

```
Item   Name     EquivItem
----   ------   ---------- 
100    bubba    106
103    gump     109
106    shrimp   100
109    grits    103
```

And the resulting table would be:

```
Item   Name     EquivItem
-----  -----    ----------
100    bubba    106
103    gump     109
```

I was using a couple nested loops in sequential code to filter out the duplicates, but finally wrote a query that works but feels like a hack.

I'm arbitrarily using a WHERE (Item < EquivItem) to select only one of the rows.  The actual tables are a bit more complex and I'm afraid there may be a case where this doesn't work.

```
SELECT *
FROM T
WHERE Item < EquivItem
```

I'm trying to take some time to figure out the right way to do things before I develop too many bad habits.  Any suggestions?  Thanks.

Comment: What is the primary key on the table?  Can Item and EquivItem have duplicates in them?  I'm assuming not, just wondering if there are any constraints on the data.

Comment: So to clarify: Every item has one and only one equivalent? In this case, I don't see where Item < EquivItem would fail.

Comment: @CtrlDot Item is the primary key.  There should be no duplicates.

Comment: @inflagranti I am *almost* completely certain that is true.

Comment: @chip: Easy to find out: 
SELECT Count(*)
FROM T
WHERE Item < EquivItem. If thats half of the rows, then yes :)

Comment: @inflagranti: Sure it's easy now that you mentioned it :) - the easy things are still difficult for me.  Going down that trail actually turns up a couple of nasty rows that I need to take a closer look at.

Comment: If Item and EquivItem must not be null and cannot be duplicated, and they're of a type that can be compared, then you only have three cases to consider: Item = EquivItem, Item < EquivItem, and Item > EquivItem. If the first case cannot exist, then the rest of your rows fall into the last two cases, half in each group, and your solution should work. Perhaps the issue is with the data ... rather than using "double links" in a table like this, you could populate EquivItem only for rows you wish to return in this query and use a join to get the "EquivItem" for the other rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it possible for more than two items to be equivalent, such as 100 = 103 = 106? Can this happen?

```
Item   Name     EquivItem
----   ------   ---------- 
100    bubba    103
103    gump     106
106    shrimp   103
```

As long as the the equivalents can't be chained together, and always have a 1-to-1 relationship, your solution looks perfectly fine to me.

If this scenario can happen, I would first scrub the data to make sure that all the EquivItems refer to the lowest Item ID in the chain... and then your original query would still do the job.

Comment: My understanding of the data leads me to believe the a = b = c case will never occur.  But i was worried about that case and future cases.